# How can I read from MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I need to read from a database. I'm under Windows. I get this error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for localhost

This is an extract from my code:

```
public class JavaApplication10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn  = null;        
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            Properties connInfo = new Properties();
            
            connInfo.put("characterEncoding","UTF8");
            connInfo.put("user", "root");
            connInfo.put("password", "goskomstat");
            
            conn  = DriverManager.getConnection("localhost", connInfo);
```

Being in Windows command line I can type:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -u root -p
```

Then I enter the password 'goskomstat' and can operate my databases.

What can I try next?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/: you'll need the MySQL JDBC driver, and you'll need to use appropriate URL and code, described in its documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your connection as follows:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", connInfo);
```

That allows you to specify the JDBC driver by using the specific URI prefix.

Comment: It hasn't helped. This is what I get now: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/

Comment: Then, you are indeed missing the driver and should use the  [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) provided by JB Nizet.

Comment: I seem to have installed it. I remember that I specially downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar. And installed it. Then when installing MySQL, I seemed to have automatically installed MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3. How can I check whether the driver is working?

Comment: You need the mysql jdbc jar file.

Comment: This is what I've got: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/. Already installed. My MySQL server is 5.6.16. Is it Ok, or it is completely not what I need? By the way, I've searched my computer. No jdbc file found.

Comment: In the file you downloaded, there is a jar file (ends with .jar), you need to add the jar to your class path in your IDE.

Comment: I use NetBeans. Added the path to the jar file Ant Variables. I mean I created CLASSPATH variable and added the path to this mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar. Not working still.

Comment: What do you mean you created classpath? Follow the following tutorial to add the proper jar (some jars mentioned in the video are optional): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8_EcAECDkA

Comment: Deleted the Ant Variable I created. And checked what I have in libraries. Please, have a look: [link](http://yadi.sk/d/XbNnw4LnJNW8J). So, it seems, that the driver was already installed.

Comment: Try adding the following before calling the connection: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` if you have an issue with that, the jar hasn't been properly added to the build path of the project.

Comment: try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }  
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
        { 

        } 
        
        try {
            Properties connInfo = new Properties();
            
            connInfo.put("characterEncoding","UTF8");
            connInfo.put("user", "root");
            connInfo.put("password", "goskomstat");                        
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", connInfo);

Comment: Added this. Not working. The same error.java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost